# Understanding Asp.net MVC Architecture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC architecture and I want learn ASP.NET MVC basics. In the article called "[Model View Controller, Model View Presenter, and Model View ViewModel Design Patterns](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42830/Model-View-Controller-Model-View-Presenter-and-Mod)" I learned some good points about MVC. I saw in the article that every model has some views as observers. So model uses `observer pattern`. When some state in the model changes, all views are notified. However, as I know, ASP.NET MVC only shows one view at a time. So, is strange to me is HOW this applies to Microsoft Asp.NET MVC. Can I say that model has only one observer (view) to notify in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700568/whos-responsible-for-the-next-view/3700740#3700740

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in MVC architecture, Model is an Object which will be used to pass data between controller to view and vice-versa.
Hence, if a Model is changed by controller then, the view when it is to be rendered to user gets the data from Model.

Answer (score 0):

View change in ASP MVC is triggered by specific controller method execution for given view.

Every view has specific controller method assigned to it, so the view can be presented as response of controller call by user.

For example, you have view in which you show grid of rows fetched from database. You click "Next" button on the bottom of site in order to go to second page. What you basically do, is invoking controller method, which takes page number as parameter. This controller method calls the database for data, based on page number you want to display, get those db entities (as model classes) and pass them to view, in order to display them.

View change is triggered by controller. Model is your data/logic representation. This can by POCO classes, your algorithms, database connections, etc.

Another example, you type into your browser address:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035611/understanding-asp-net-mvc-architecture
```

By doing that and pressing ENTER, you tell StackOverflow site to launch controller named "questions", and you pass parameters to it, which are 18035611 and "understanding-asp-net-mvc-architecture". What the controller does is fetching necessery data from database, converts it to model objects and send it to view in order to display them in it's HTML code.

Of course this is only analogy. I'm not sure what technology is SO using, but if it used ASP MVC, it would just be as I described.

Comment: as I know, in MVC architecture, controller will be selected at runtime using strategy pattern!